How to Open File
I am new to Vim. I wish to learn how to open a file from within Vim. I have examined every cheat sheet on internet but found no answer other than :e[dit] file - edit a file in a new buffer which always fails with an error message of
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)


I’m voting to close this question because it's basic usage. It's possible to figure it out by reading the documentation.

Vim documents are contained within Vim itself. Please, stop googling and start to read the help pages instead.
The whole user manual is accessed by the command :h user-manual (or by appropriate menu item in gvim). Your particular question is discussed in all details at the very top of the chapter 7 (direct link is :h usr_07.txt). Sorry, I'm not going to copy-paste that text here. Better if you get it opened and read inside Vim.
Also, all error messages are documented too. So the command :h E37 will show yet another (brief) explanation and advice concerning your problem. In fact, in the mentioned above topic :h usr_07.txt this is also directly suggested.

You might want to add that all the error messages are also in :help. Typing :help E37 will give OP an exact explanation of their problem and two ways to fix it.

:h E37 has an answer:
Vim protects you from losing your work.  You can either write the changed
file with ":w", or, if  you are sure, abandon it anyway, and lose all the
changes.  This can be done by adding a '!' character just after the command
you used.  Example: 
    :e other_file
changes to: 
    :e! other_file

Another option is to open the file in a new tab, with :tabnew other_file, or a split window with :sp other_file or :vsp other_file. Learn about tabs in :h tabpage.txt, and splits in :h usr_08 or :h windows.txt
